# Text between before the actual description in a description list

Tags: enumitem, description

How do I insert a custom (constant) text before all item descriptions in a description list?

For instance, I want to create something like this:

```
 Question 1: My question
 Answer: My answer
```

Generated from a code like:

```
\begin{questionsandanswers}
    \item[My question] My Answer
\end{questionsandanswers}
```

I'm using enumitem to edit some parts of the description list. My code until now follows:

```
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \newcounter{descriptcount}
    \newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
    \setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
      before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
              \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}}
      ,font=\textbf{\stepcounter{descriptcount}Question \thedescriptcount:~} \normalfont
    }
    \setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
      before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
              \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\alph{descriptcount}}}
      ,font=\textbf{\stepcounter{descriptcount}Question \thedescriptcount:~} \normalfont
    }

    \newenvironment{questionsandanswers}{\begin{enumdescript}[style=nextline,labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=\parindent]}{\end{enumdescript}}
```

With such a code a get something like:

```
Question 1: My question
My answer
```

But I can't find how to put the "Answer" word before the actual answer. Also, follows a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt,a4paper]

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}}
  ,font= \textbf{\stepcounter{descriptcount}Question \thedescriptcount.~} \normalfont
}
\setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\alph{descriptcount}}}
  ,font= \textbf{\stepcounter{descriptcount}Question \thedescriptcount.~} \normalfont
}


\newenvironment{questionsandanswers}{\begin{enumdescript}[style=nextline,labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=\parindent]}{\end{enumdescript}}

\begin{document}

Desired syntax:

\begin{questionsandanswers}

    \item[My question] My answer

\end{questionsandanswers}

Desired result:

\begin{questionsandanswers}

    \item[My question] \textbf{Answer:} My answer

\end{questionsandanswers}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I would use an interface that resembles `\begin{questionsandanswers} \newquestion This is the question? \newanswer This is the answer. \newquestion This is another question? \newanswer This is another answer. \end{questionsandanswers}`, or even simplify it to `\question` and `\answer`. Are you open to such a suggestion?

Comment: @Werner I though of such solution, but it is more loose than my desired syntax. By replacing the \item by two separated commands I let go off the need for an actual answer. One can  put several \question without appearing a single \answer. Other solution would be an \questionanswer{My Question}{My Answer} (two parameters), but I really want to know if it can be done using the \item ...

Comment: @Isma: You can force the user to require a `\newanswer` with every `\newquestion`, thereby not "let[ting] go of the need for an actual answer".

Answer (score 4):

Here's a rather hacky way to achieve your desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}}
  ,font= \textbf{\stepcounter{descriptcount}Question \thedescriptcount.~} \normalfont
}
\setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\alph{descriptcount}}}
  ,font= \textbf{\stepcounter{descriptcount}Question \thedescriptcount.~} \normalfont
}


\newenvironment{questionsandanswers}
  {% \begin{questionsandanswers}
    \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
      \hspace\labelsep
      \normalfont\bfseries##1}%
      \let\oldnewline\newline
      \renewcommand{\newline}{\oldnewline\textbf{Answer:}\hspace\labelsep}
    \begin{enumdescript}[style=nextline,labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=\parindent]
  }{% \end{questionsandanswers}
    \end{enumdescript}
  }

\begin{document}

Desired syntax:

\begin{questionsandanswers}
  \item[My question] My answer
\end{questionsandanswers}

\end{document}
```

I'd much rather prefer the following setup though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}}
  ,font= \bfseries
}
\setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\alph{descriptcount}}}
  ,font= \bfseries
}
\newcommand{\newquestion}{%
  \stepcounter{descriptcount}%
  \item[Question~\thedescriptcount.]}
\newcommand{\newanswer}{%
  \par\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
  \item[Answer:]}

\newenvironment{questionsandanswers}
  {% \begin{questionsandanswers}
    \begin{enumdescript}[labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=\parindent]
  }{% \end{questionsandanswers}
    \end{enumdescript}
  }

\begin{document}

Desired syntax:

\begin{questionsandanswers}
  \newquestion My question
  \newanswer My answer
  \newquestion Another question
  \newanswer Another answer
\end{questionsandanswers}

\end{document}
```

The above doesn't force the user to have a `\newanswer` with every `\newquestion`. However, you can force this with the following definitions `\newquestion`:

```
\long\def\newquestion#1\newanswer{%
  \stepcounter{descriptcount}%
  \item[Question~\thedescriptcount.] #1
  \newanswer}
```

The parameter text of `\newquestion` now includes `\newanswer`. As such, without it in the input stream, TeX will complain, forcing the user to have a `\newanswer` with every `\newquestion`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt,a4paper]

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter   
\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newenvironment{questionsandanswers}{\list{}{%
\labelwidth0pt\itemindent-\leftmargin
              \let\makelabel\qudescriptionlabel}
              \def\item[##1]{%
              \@inmatherr\item
              \@item[##1]\ \par\hspace{-\leftmargin}\textbf{Answer:}}}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother
\newcommand\qudescriptionlabel[1]{%
            \refstepcounter{descriptcount}\hspace\labelsep
            \normalfont\bfseries Question \thedescriptcount.~ #1}


\begin{document}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it was almost effective. However, I couldn't put a line break before "Answer". I tried to put `\normalfont\bfseries Question \thedescriptcount.~ #1 \\ Answer: }`, also tried `\normalfont\bfseries Question \thedescriptcount.~ #1 \newline Answer: }` (both with and withoud `\hfill`).

Comment: Yes this is enside sbox so no line break here

Comment: @Isma I edit my answer.